# sql athena/presto check if value in array of nested json

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I run a query in athena like so:

```
SELECT element_at(col_name,1).entities FROM "db_name"."the_table" limit 10;
```

and I get an array of nested jsons/dicts like so:

```
[{country=US,content=content},{country=DE,content=content},{country=GB,content=content}]
[]
[{country=HK,content=content},{country=IN,content=content},{country=GB,content=content}]
[]
```

and I want to create a query which extracts the row if any of the `country=US`.

So I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM "db_name"."the_table" WHERE any_match(element_at(col_name,1).entities, e-> e.country= 'US') limit 10;
```

but this crashes saying its not a row

I would like to extract rows where the country is US..

Comment: 1) What is the result of `SELECT typeof(element_at(col_name,1).entities) FROM ...`? 2) can you please add desired output for the provided data?

Comment: @GuruStron it spits out type `array(row(country varchar, content varchar`..

Comment: Then the error does not make much sense to me. Can you please add full error text?

Comment: it says `COLUMN_NOT_FOUND: line 1:66: Column 'col_name' cannot be resolved or requester is not authorized to access requested resources` which is weird because I can see the array

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing actual query and data.

Comment: @GuruStron bizzarely it works as intended now.. not sure what was wrong earlier (iam a sql newbie) :( sorry to have wasted your time, I have accepted your answer nonetheless.

Comment: @GuruStron I have a follow up quetsion if you do not mind. your answer: `any_match(element_at(col_name,1).entities, e -> e.country = 'US')` works for the first element.. what if if have to loop through N elements of it?

Comment: You need to expand a bit on the topic. Again - sample data and desired output should help a lot.

Comment: @GuruStron yea I managed to solve it looks like I needed an inner `element_at` and that resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any_match(element_at(col_name,1).entities, e -> e.country = 'US')` should work for `ROW` type.

There is another type which can be written in output in this way - it is `MAP`, so you can try:

```
WHERE any_match(element_at(col_name,1).entities, e -> e['country'] = 'US')
```

or (if the key is optional):

```
WHERE any_match(element_at(col_name,1).entities, e-> element_at(e, 'country') = 'US')
```

Answer (score 0):

WHERE any_match(element_at(col_name,1).entities, e-> element_at(e, 'country') = 'US')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).